# Уязвимость $_SESSION

Tags: php, безопасность, сессия

Здравствуйте, хотелось бы узнать возможно ли изменить $_SESSION?
И как это сделать?

Comment: например с помощью инъекции или другими словами тот, кто имеет доступ к серверу на выполнения кода или изменения файлов

Answer (score 0):

Можно.

```
$_SESSION = 'да, я очень плохой мальчик';
```

...
5. PROFIT!

[Ссылка1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/535069/269365), [ссылка2(eng)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6483097/8737307)

Странно, что везде пишут по-разному, но при этом все вопросы отмечены как решенные. Думаю, здесь не обошлось без [сами знаете кого](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE).